# Go gRPC build chain: Should I enforce go get -u on every build?

Tags: docker, go, dependencies, grpc

I am using a repo to store my proto definitions and adding this as a go module.

The issue is: When someone clones the code they get a reference to the proto definitions for the commit when it was either added or go get -u was last called.

How can I enforce current definitions being used consistently? I am using Docker to build containers. Should I add go get -u as a build step and have the developer run into builds failing?

Comment: There's no package manager for Protobufs thus users of the protobufs directly (!?) must ensure they're e.g. `git pull`'ing source containing repos to get latest versions. It is relatively common to generate stubs and publish these alongside the protobuf sources. The burden is on the protobuf source developer to trigger rebuilds of the stubs whenever changes are made and on the users of the stubs to (periodically) update. Consider using releases as a way to guide your downstream developers.

Comment: If your code has a hard dependency on a particular version of your protos, why keep it in a separate repo? It's a hard dependency, and you own/control both repos... Alternatively, you can just use `go mod` to add the proto dep to your project, and update the dependency when you need to, so that anyone who clones the repo will fetch the correct version. That being said, if you absolutely need the versions to be up to date, I'm not sure if your current approach makes all that much sense to begin with

Comment: I also struggle to see the reason why the proto files are all that important that they need to be manually updated/pulled and be part of a build step. Just generate the pb.go files, and add those as a dependency

Comment: are your proto files in another git repository?

Comment: My proto files and built proto go files are part of a seperate repository.
I do know how to deal with stuff like reserved, etc. very well, I just wondered i I needed to add another step to ensure consistency between proto versions or if relying on proper .proto "lifecycle" management was enough.